# Foreach on the first element of list

Tags: scala

I have a list of tuples, where each tuple is of type `(String, String)`.

A sample list can be: `List((A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (A,E), (B,C), (B,A), (B,D), (B,E), (C,A), (C,B), (C,D), (C,E),...)`.

I want to do two things on this list:

- Shuffle the list according to the first element randomly, ie. considering above example, the 4 items of first element `A` should be shuffled in a random order, but should stay together. For Example, it may then look like: `(A,E),(A,D),(A,B),(A,C),(B,A),(B,E),(B,C),(B,D)...` etc.
- Pick 3 items of each of the first element from the shuffled list

I'm not able to figure out the logic for both of them combined, because if we do `Random.shuffle()` and then a `.take()`, it might `take` in any given order, not necessarily 3 for each of the first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first group by the first element, shuffle the inner lists, and then extract 3 tuples from those lists and flatten at the end

```
list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => Random.shuffle(v).take(3) }.flatten
```

Output will look something like:

```
List((A,C), (A,B), (A,E), (B,A), (B,C), (B,E), (C,E), (C,D), (C,A), (D,C), (D,A), (D,B) ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
def pickNRandomByKey[K : Ordering, V](n: Int)(data: List[(K, V)]): List[(K, List[V])] =
  data
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
    .view
    .mapValues(group => Random.shuffle(group).take(n))
    .toList
    .sortBy(_._1)
```

Comment: Ideally yes, that would definitely be something I want, where I have a list of first letter and list of randomly picked second letter from the first letter.This might do my job (I havent tested), but the accepted answer looks way simpler and memory isn't really a concern for me.